# Efficient Way To Create Adjacency Matrix in Stata?

Tags: stata, adjacency-matrix

**I have data that looks like this in Stata:**

```
Cat#1    Cat#2
  A        X
  B        X
  A        Y
  C        Z
 ...      ...
```

I want to create an adjacency that I will later output to Matlab for further analysis.

**Here is my proposed way of doing it:**

- Create a column for each of the unique elements in Cat#2 (i.e. columns: X Y Z in the above example).
- Collapse across CAT#1 so that only one row for each unique Cat#1 value (i.e. rows: A B C in the example above).
- Replace each column element of X Y Z ... by 1 IF the "entry" > 0.
- Drop excess stuff, left with adjacency (matrix) dataset.

The problem is that I have a lot of unique categories for Cat#2, so I think that coding up this part would take a long time.  Are there any suggestions on what I can do to speed up the process of creating the sought data structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Demonstration of some coding attempt is advised. And it's not clear what "entry" means in the third bullet point. On the first point, you could use the command `levels` to acquire a local containing all of the unique values. Then the creation of new variables can be easily done with a `foreach` loop through that local.

Comment: Try reshaping to wide format.

Comment: @AspenChen You probably intended `levelsof` rather than `levels`, which is an out-of-date command as of Stata 9 (though it still continues to work).

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thanks. `levelsof` it is. Although now rethinking about this, a simple `collapse` of the counts of each unique combination and then `reshape` into wide as @NealFultz suggests would create the structure.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Will give reshaping the data into wide-form a try.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few Stata commands for making adjacency matrices.

Try typing `findit netsis` or `findit nwcommands` at the command prompt.